# Converting data back to its original items

Tags: c, data-conversion, shift

I have some code and I don't understand how to get the individual items back:

```
u32_t foo = ((u32_t)((d) & 0xff) << 24) | ((u32_t)((c) & 0xff) << 16) |  
((u32_t)((b) & 0xff) << 8)  | (u32_t)((a) & 0xff)
```

I would like to input the result of this conversion 
I want this to convert a IP address back to its parts to display.
But when I enter 192 168 1 200 I get 0xC801A8C0 and I don't get it converted back.

Does anyone know how I can items in a union struct?
I try to use LwIP but have problems with union structs. I try to access local_ip and remote_ip.
[image: struct]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
u32_t d = (foo >> 24) & 0xFF; // Get the bits 32nd...25th
u32_t c = (foo >> 16) & 0xFF; // 24th...17th
u32_t b = (foo >> 8) & 0xFF;  // 16th...9th
u32_t a = (foo) & 0xFF;       // 8th...1st
```

This is actually doing the opposite of the code above.

Comment: @Dylan Then your inputs might be bigger than 0xFF, in that case, there is no way to convert them back I'm afraid, since the higher bits are discarded with `& 0xFF`

Comment: ah i did something wrong in my calculator the program works tnx

Answer (score 1):

You can mask out the values inside `foo`

```
u32_t thisWasD = (foo & 0xff000000) >> 24; // ==> will null out the lowest 24 bits
u32_t thisWasC = (foo & 0x00ff0000) >> 16; // ==> will null out the upper 8 and lowest 16 bit
u32_t thisWasB = (foo & 0x0000ff00) >> 8; // ==> etc
u32_t thisWasA = (foo & 0xff) // etc - no shift needed
```

and shift them back so they are alignt in fist 8 bit ( by 24,16,8 - last one is already ok

Answer (score 0):

it's like you have one `int input` and you want to divide into bytes by bytes & store each bytes in seperate integers

```
int main() {


         a = ((uint32_t)((foo) & 0x000000ff) << 24);
         b = ((uint32_t)((foo) & 0x0000ff00) << 16);
         c = ((uint32_t)((foo) & 0x00ff0000) << 8);
         d = ((uint32_t)((foo) & 0xff000000);

}
```